# JQ command returning duplicate IDs for different data

Tags: command-line, networking

Today, I've tried putting in values into our program, but I keep getting duplicate results.

```
curl -s http://cd0a4a.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes|jq -r '["version", "GPU_driver", "miner", "gpu", "rigname"],(.rigs[] | [.version, .driver, .miner, "\(.gpus)/\(.miner_instance)","0d6b27"])| @csv' | csvlook -I
```

Gives me the result:

```
| version | GPU_driver | miner    | gpu | rigname |
| ------- | ---------- | -------- | --- | ------- |
| 1.2.3   | nvidia     | ethminer | 2/2 | 0d6b27  |
| 1.2.4   | amdgpu     | ethminer | 1/1 | 0d6b27  |
```

As opposed to the intended result of:

```
| version | GPU_driver | miner    | gpu | rigname |
| ------- | ---------- | -------- | --- | ------- |
| 1.2.3   | nvidia     | ethminer | 2/2 | 0d6b27  |
| 1.2.4   | amdgpu     | ethminer | 1/1 | 50dc35  |
```

Comment: both are exactly the same...

Comment: no its not the same see last column

Comment: i need to print two values 0d6b27 and 50dc35 but it still resounding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `to_entries[]` to get the json key. ([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226370/jq-print-key-and-value-for-each-entry-in-an-object))

This works for me:

```
curl -s http://cd0a4a.ethosdistro.com/?json=yes \
| jq -r '["version", "GPU_driver", "miner", "gpu", "rigname"],(.rigs | to_entries[] | [.value.version, .value.driver, .value.miner,"\(.value.gpus)/\(.value.miner_instance)", .key]) | @csv' \
| csvlook
```

Comment: really really really thanks man i appreciate this from you